# How to get relevant tips in input select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I ran into a problem when entering an address into the input, what is the point, prompts come from the server to the address and I display these prompts in AsyncSelect, but the fact is that I always get the previous state, for example, I enter the address: street 22, and I just get a straight, then I enter 33, and I get 22, how do I get what the user entered? that is, the current state

```
const { addressList } = props; // get addresses to server

const [addresses, setAddresses] = useState(null);

<AsyncSelect
  cacheOptions
  defaultOptions={addressOptions}
  loadOptions={promiseOptions}
  className="modal_list-options"
  noOptionsMessage="Error find"
  placeholder="Enter address..."
  onChange={handleChangeSelectAddress}
/>

const promiseOptions = (inputValue) => {
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   resolve(onFilteredAddress(inputValue));
  }, 1000);
 });
};

const onFilteredAddress = async (address) => {
 const finallyAddress = `${selectedCity} ${address}`;
  if (address) {
   const success = await onHandleGetAddressList(finallyAddress).then(
    (data) => {
      setAddresses(data); // setState adresses
      return true;
    }
   );
   if (success) {
    return addressesList;
   } else {
      return addressOptions;
   }
 }
};

const addressesList = useMemo(() => {
 if (addresses) {
  const { payload } = addresses;
  const { data } = payload;
  const { suggestions } = data;
  return suggestions.map((el) => {
   return {
     value: el,
     label: el,
   };
  });
} else {
   return addressOptions; // defaultOptions
}
}, [test, addressList]);
```

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to Stack Overflow! I can't really make sense of your description. Please read the following [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: The `useMemo` should have the dependent values in the array argument:
`[addresses.payload.data.suggestions]`